# Positioning of log-polar plot axis labels in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I have trouble positioning the axis labels in this plot. I like to position the top label so that the pipe aligns with the grid, and the right and left labels so that they do not touch the plot.

I tried

```
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', pad=15)
```

but it has no effect. Also,

```
rcParams
```

seems to conflict with the log-scale of the plot. As a hack, I tried whitespaces but these are stripped of LaTeX at the beginning and end of each word. Finally, I tried invisible Unicode signs but only got matplotlib to crash.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

[log-polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoHbJ.png)
[image]

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
ax.set_xticks(numpy.linspace(0, 2 * 3.14, 4, endpoint=False))
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(3.14 / 2.0)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)
ax.set_xticklabels([
    r'$100,000\,{\rm yr}|10\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$100\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$1000\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$10,000\,{\rm yr}$'],
    fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick can be to align the textlabels differently according to their position. That is, the left label should be aligned right, the right label left.

For the top label, it makes sense to split it up, such that the first label is left aligned and the last label is right aligned.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ticks = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5, endpoint=True)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(3.14 / 2.0)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)
ax.set_xticklabels([
    r'$10\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$100\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$1000\,{\rm yr}$',
    r'$10,000\,{\rm yr}$', r"$100,000\,{\rm yr}|$"],
    fontsize=16)

aligns = ["left", "left", "center", "right", "right"]
for tick, align in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), aligns):
    tick.set_ha(align)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works great.